# ora-22060 argument is an invalid or uninitialized number

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I'm trying to create MView in orcale bat it raise error.  I don't know why or how to fix this.
it is my  code

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MAKT REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND
WITH ROWID
START WITH TO_DATE('03-11-2018 01:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') NEXT TRUNC(SYSDATE+12/24,'HH') 

AS
SELECT "MAKT"."MANDT" "MANDT",
       "MAKT"."MATNR" "MATNR",
       "MAKT"."SPRAS" "SPRAS",
       "MAKT"."MAKTX" "MAKTX"
  FROM "MAKT"@"PE2.ABC.COM.VN" "MAKT"
 WHERE "MAKT"."MANDT" = '300';
```

It gives error

> ora-22060 :argument is an invalid or uninitialized number ora-06512
>   :ora-06512 at sys.dbms_snapshot line 1613 ora-06512 : at line 1

please help me.

Comment: This might be something to raise with Oracle support.